# Train of thought with submit data Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, logic

My question is very specific and not for all, I want people to help me with my train of thought.

What I want to build : for example I have service where all people (not logined) can create they post with some data like news and publish it for money.

How I think it should be built (in 2 steps):

1. Man click on the link to page with form that create posts and router go to this page
2. He fills data and click submit
3. Server checked form and if all OK, session.set this data that he fills and route to the next step (pay money 
   to publish they post)
4. (I want to build this with stripe so) He clicked on stripe checkout button and pay some $$, if he paid then show message, all ok, we session.get data that he fills from previous step, and on server we insert his post and go it, if not show message that something wrong

Technical Plan session.set session.get, it is right ?
And if someone slip through form with fills and go to payment page, how to check it ? If session.get === undefind or something like this, reroute to previous step ?

As you can see I have a lot of questions, and I cant find answers in google or some documentation tutorials and etc. maybe some have answers to it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very wide. Consider narrowing it.

Your 2 first points make sense. It's ok. The third and forth are wrong.

> Technical Plan session.set session.get, it is right ?

No it is not. You plan to use the information you hold in a `Session` variable to publish data validated on client side. It does not ensure the validity of your data. This is a bad idea because anyone can open the console and edit the data to make it different/invalid regarding your rules of validation. All it takes is a `Session.set ("yourData", "YouHaveBeenHacked");`

What you need is to call a Meteor method on server side to add an entry to a dedicated collection. You add another field (e.g; `status`) to keep track of the post payment and publication and return the data entry `_id` that you store in a `Session` variable.

This way, your method can return an error if the data does not fit into your requirements.

Side note: you also need to add a CRON job serverside to get rid of all the old post tentatives that have not been paid for (user left his browser, he closed tab, etc.).

Comment: Consider not answering very broad questions. It often leads to extended comment discussions (here I can already sense the "What would the method look like?"...). These questions might be quickly closed and/or deleted and your work will be fruitless.

Comment: @kyll sorry man, but "What would the method look like?" not for me, I am new wild child in web and I have a goal, I need it to achieve very fast, 
So make your conclusions

Comment: @Billybobbonnet ok, so I removed session, and after validate post insert it in special collection, and if man pay me I return this post to another collection where I show all payment posts, right ?

Comment: you validate it both in client and in method, on server, before inserting it. The collection you use to displayed paid post should be the same, you just distinguish paid and non-paid using a `status` field.